# Manage arguments that receive no values

Tags: python, argparse

Hi All i am working on writing  help menu for my application. Code is below

```
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Hyla database backup application")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-g","--group",type=str,help="defines database groups")
    group.add_argument("-a","--all",help="backup all databases",action="store_true")
    group.add_argument("-D","--databases",nargs='+',help="take multiple databases as input")
    parser.add_argument("-r","--reference",help="backups reference data-only",action="store_true")

    args=parser.parse_args()
   if args.reference==True:
     alpha=True
     print alpha
   if args.group == "uat":
     print args.group
   arglist=args.databases
   if len(arglist) > 0:
    for i in args.databases:
    print i
```

My real problem is that if user do not uses the -D option then value of arglist is 0.I am trying to handle this by checking if arglist has any value and perform next steps only if arglist is nonempty. But it seems the value of arglist is empty instead of zero so, that's why i am getting below error

```
PS G:\pythonargs> python .\args.py -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\args.py", line 17, in <module>
if len(arglist) > 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
PS G:\pythonargs>
```

i want to perform actions on the basis of the value in arglist.How can i make sure that even if user do not uses -D option ,arglist should have some value

Comment: The default `default` for most arguments is `None`.  That's the cause of your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default value for that option to a list:

```
group.add_argument("-D","--databases",nargs='+',
  default=[],
  help="take multiple databases as input")
```

Now if the user does not use the `-D` option it will be an empty list, so you can test it's length with `len()` or use it in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since arglist can be None, you can do this:

```
if arglist:
    if len(arglist) > 0:
        for i in args.databases:
            print (i)
```

and only test for length if arglist is not None.

I combined the two tests into one if statement,

```
if arglist and len(arglist) > 0:
```

which works because Python evaluates left to right and the implementation I used does not bother to evaluate the expression on the right side of the 'and' operator if the expression on the left side fails.  I do not know if that is always true for every implementation.